# Perl keeps flashing when running command Windows 10

Tags: perl

I have installed Perl but every time I run a command it flash and goes away and does nothing, I have added it to Environment  path and  gave full permission to folder Perl64

edit regeristy in perl  command c:\perl\bin\perl.exe %1 %*

when I run Perl -v I do get versions so I know it installed

Comment: Are you running your commands from the command line? Or by double clicking a perl file?

Comment: I guess you double click the script to run it, it finishes, and it closes?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your command ran to completion and exited. Once the program exits, the console is closed.

Perhaps you are getting an error. You should run the program from the command line to see what errors you get.

You could also try associating the file with the following command:

```
cmd /c c:\perl\bin\perl.exe %1 %* & pause
```

(Untested)